# How to render local PDF file with PDF.js library?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf

I have some PDF files stored on my computer in my local directory (C:/Users/.../.../Documents/file.pdf). I need to render them into HTML5 and show in browser. To accomplish that, I'm using a PDF.js library but it only works for URL links of PDF files that are stored online, but not the ones from my local directory. The error I get says "Missing PDF".

I would greatly appreciate your help.

The code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/2.2.228/pdf.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

#show-pdf-button {
    width: 150px;
    display: block;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#file-to-upload {
    display: none;
}

#pdf-main-container {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

#pdf-loader {
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 13px;
    line-height: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}

#pdf-contents {
    display: none;
}

#pdf-meta {
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0 0 20px 0;
}

#pdf-buttons {
    float: left;
}

#page-count-container {
    float: right;
}

#pdf-current-page {
    display: inline;
}

#pdf-total-pages {
    display: inline;
}

#pdf-canvas {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#page-loader {
    height: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    display: none;
    color: #999999;
    font-size: 13px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

<button id="show-pdf-button">Show PDF</button> 

<div id="pdf-main-container">
    <div id="pdf-loader">Loading document ...</div>
    <div id="pdf-contents">
        <div id="pdf-meta">
            <div id="pdf-buttons">
                <button id="pdf-prev">Previous</button>
                <button id="pdf-next">Next</button>
            </div>
            <div id="page-count-container">Page <div id="pdf-current-page"></div> of <div id="pdf-total-pages"></div></div>
        </div>
        <canvas id="pdf-canvas" width="400"></canvas>
        <div id="page-loader">Loading page ...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>

var _PDF_DOC,
    _CURRENT_PAGE,
    _TOTAL_PAGES,
    _PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0,
    _CANVAS = document.querySelector('#pdf-canvas');

// initialize and load the PDF
async function showPDF(pdf_url) {
    document.querySelector("#pdf-loader").style.display = 'block';

    // get handle of pdf document
    try {
        _PDF_DOC = await pdfjsLib.getDocument({ url: pdf_url });
    }
    catch(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }

    // total pages in pdf
    _TOTAL_PAGES = _PDF_DOC.numPages;
    
    // Hide the pdf loader and show pdf container
    document.querySelector("#pdf-loader").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#pdf-contents").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#pdf-total-pages").innerHTML = _TOTAL_PAGES;

    // show the first page
    showPage(1);
}

// load and render specific page of the PDF
async function showPage(page_no) {
    _PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 1;
    _CURRENT_PAGE = page_no;

    // disable Previous & Next buttons while page is being loaded
    document.querySelector("#pdf-next").disabled = true;
    document.querySelector("#pdf-prev").disabled = true;

    // while page is being rendered hide the canvas and show a loading message
    document.querySelector("#pdf-canvas").style.display = 'none';
    document.querySelector("#page-loader").style.display = 'block';

    // update current page
    document.querySelector("#pdf-current-page").innerHTML = page_no;
    
    // get handle of page
    try {
        var page = await _PDF_DOC.getPage(page_no);
    }
    catch(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }

    // original width of the pdf page at scale 1
    var pdf_original_width = page.getViewport(1).width;
    
    // as the canvas is of a fixed width we need to adjust the scale of the viewport where page is rendered
    var scale_required = _CANVAS.width / pdf_original_width;

    // get viewport to render the page at required scale
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale_required);

    // set canvas height same as viewport height
    _CANVAS.height = viewport.height;

    // setting page loader height for smooth experience
    document.querySelector("#page-loader").style.height =  _CANVAS.height + 'px';
    document.querySelector("#page-loader").style.lineHeight = _CANVAS.height + 'px';

    // page is rendered on <canvas> element
    var render_context = {
        canvasContext: _CANVAS.getContext('2d'),
        viewport: viewport
    };
        
    // render the page contents in the canvas
    try {
        await page.render(render_context);
    }
    catch(error) {
        alert(error.message);
    }

    _PAGE_RENDERING_IN_PROGRESS = 0;

    // re-enable Previous & Next buttons
    document.querySelector("#pdf-next").disabled = false;
    document.querySelector("#pdf-prev").disabled = false;

    // show the canvas and hide the page loader
    document.querySelector("#pdf-canvas").style.display = 'block';
    document.querySelector("#page-loader").style.display = 'none';
}

// click on "Show PDF" buuton
document.querySelector("#show-pdf-button").addEventListener('click', function() {
    this.style.display = 'none';
    showPDF('C:/Users/....../file.pdf');
});

// click on the "Previous" page button
document.querySelector("#pdf-prev").addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(_CURRENT_PAGE != 1)
        showPage(--_CURRENT_PAGE);
});

// click on the "Next" page button
document.querySelector("#pdf-next").addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(_CURRENT_PAGE != _TOTAL_PAGES)
        showPage(++_CURRENT_PAGE);
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this library claim to provide the capability of displaying local PDF's in a browser?

Comment: Also, are you sure you got the path right?  `'C:/Users/....../file.pdf'` doesn't look quite right to me.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I got the right path, I just removed some path details here for privacy :) 
But the path is absolutely correct and once I paste it into the browser directly, it displays my file.
Also, I didn't find any info on the library displaying local PDF's... I did try using several other methods like iframe and it still doesn't work.

Comment: `C:/Users/....../file.pdf` is not an url. Local file should be referred by using a `file:` URI. Just drag-drop the pdf file in a browser to check the correct format.

Comment: Changing 'C:/Users/....../file.pdf' to 'file:///C:/Users/....../file.pdf' didn't work. I see the same error.